# In Python 3, how can I write two lists of strings into a csv file of two columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I currently have two lists in Python that look like:

```
list1 = ['Steve', 'Mark', 'Jeff', ... ]
list2 = ['steve@mac.com', 'mark223@mac.com', 'jeffrey@mac.com', ...]
```

From this, I am trying to create a csv file that looks like:

```
Steve   steve@mac.com
Mark    mark223@mac.com
Jeff    jeffrey@mac.com
....
```

The code I am using is:

```
import csv

with open('output.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list1,list2)
```

This results in a file that treats each character as a new cell. What am I doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) those lists together so each pair (list1, list2) is treated  as single row:

```
import csv

list1 = ['Steve', 'Mark', 'Jeff']
list2 = ['steve@mac.com', 'mark223@mac.com', 'jeffrey@mac.com']

with open('output.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(list1,list2))
```

Sample output:

```
$ cat output.csv 
Steve,steve@mac.com
Mark,mark223@mac.com
Jeff,jeffrey@mac.com
```

If you need your output to be space or tab separated (instead of comma), you can specify it as a parameter to [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). For example:

```
import csv

list1 = ['Steve', 'Mark', 'Jeff']
list2 = ['steve@mac.com', 'mark223@mac.com', 'jeffrey@mac.com']

with open('output.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(zip(list1,list2))
```

Produces:

```
$ cat output.csv 
Steve   steve@mac.com
Mark    mark223@mac.com
Jeff    jeffrey@mac.com
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)